# How do I create a header and trailer in the console using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, console-application

I'd like to construct a nice console interface for my script. I imagine it like this:

```
===================
Header information
===================
$ user input goes here
===================
Trailer information
===================
```

Now my code is like this:

```
def prompt(stage)
  puts '============================================'
  puts stage[:head]
  puts '============================================'
  print '$ '
  puts gets.chomp
  puts '============================================'
  puts stage[:tail]
  puts '============================================'
  system("clear") unless system("cls")
end
```

Of cource `stage[:tail]` doesn't prints out until the user finishes his input, and then it flushes away with `system('clear')`.

Is it possible to print something after `gets` but force the user input to the screen-line that starts with '$'.

Comment: Ruby has bindings to `curses`: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/index.html. You can build arbitrarily complex console interfaces with it.

Comment: On curses, you should use [setpos](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-setpos)

Comment: You already got it. By using `print` instead of `puts`, the cursor remains right after the prompt `$ `. Not clear what you cannot do.